# Can't see candidates in Sample SoftKeyboard android IME

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, ime

When I use the Sample SoftKeyboard given in the Android samples, no candidates(word suggestions) are generated as with the normal keyboard. Why is this?
How do I get the word suggestions?
I am trying to implement my own IME by modifying the sample soft keyboard, but need word predictions.

Do I have to provide the Candidate View class with a word&frequency list and if so how do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

There's a tut about that, which also includes the candidate detection (check the [[LINK]](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/User-Event/Exampleofwritinganinputmethodforasoftkeyboard.htm)). Also to be known, "suggestions" are enabled by default on all text areas, but will obey the global setting, so an app can't forcibly enable suggestions in any way. If you have the global setting turned off, they're off everywhere. So, you can see if this option isn't turned off in your case too.